# How to get latest room subject from ejabberd/xmpp?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-api

I changed 'Subject' of a chat room but I am not getting this latest subject name.  I am using 'disco#info' to get the room info.  In response, I am getting room title that was set initially while creating the room but not the latest room subject.  How can I get the latest room subject ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had to customize the Erlang module `mod_muc_room.erl`.

Did these changes in `iq_disco_info_extras`:

1. Created a new function `get_subject` which gets the room subject from `StateData`.
2. Added a new parameter in `iq_disco_info_extras` to get room subject and called the function `RoomSubject = get_subject(StateData)`.
3. Added a new `RFIELD` as `?RFIELD(<<"Room subject">>,
            <<"muc#roominfo_subject">>, RoomSubject)`,
4. Compiled the module `mod_muc_room.erl`, which updated the `mod_muc_room.beam` file.

Tada...that worked like a piece of cake!

Now getting subject name in `roominfo`.

Comment: Since this answer is a little outdated (specifically step 3), If anyone is struggling to get it working, I have created a fork for these changes to the latest repo [here](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/commit/c48e78579210880131b8d62cc7106951e73f8df0)

Answer (score 2):

In XMPP MUC protocol, Subject and title are two different things. The title is set via configuration form and can be displayed in service discovery. Subject is a dynamic topic that is send to participant when he joins the room. Subject is not send back in disco#info query. Only name and room_description are send back in discovery info.

Comment: I agree with you. But if i change the subject for the room, i am not getting it in disco#info. I am always getting the old subject.

Comment: As I said, subject is not displayed in disco#info. You get name and room_description, but not subject. You are not getting old subject, you are getting a description, which is separate data.

Comment: As I said: "Subject is a dynamic topic that is send to participant when he joins the room." In other words, you need to join the room to get the subject.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still looking for this, here's a quick way to do this from something like an ejabberd plugin/module:

```
{ok,Room_PID} = mod_muc:find_online_room(<<"my_muc_room_name">>, <<"conference.my.server.com">>),    
{ok,Room_State} = p1_fsm:sync_send_all_state_event(Room_PID, get_state),    
Room_Subject_List = Room_State#state.subject,    
Room_Subject = hd(Room_Subject_List),    
Subject = Room_Subject#text.data,    
io:format("~ts~n", [Subject]).
```

If you're trying this from an erlang shell you brought up via "ejabberdctl debug", then you'll also want to pull in the record definitions for "state" and "text".  To do that, create a textfile called something like "my_record_includes.hrl" with content something like the following (of course, you'll have to adjust the filepaths based on your ejabberd installation).

```
-include("/opt/ejabberd-19.05/lib/xmpp-1.3.4/include/jid.hrl").
-include("/opt/ejabberd-19.05/lib/xmpp-1.3.4/include/xmpp_codec.hrl").
-include("/opt/ejabberd-19.05/lib/ejabberd-19.05/include/mod_muc_room.hrl").
```

Once you have "my_record_includes.hrl" created, then use the shell "rr" command to import it like this:

```
> rr("my_record_includes.hrl").

[activity,address,addresses,adhoc_actions,adhoc_command,
 adhoc_note,avatar_data,avatar_info,avatar_meta,
 avatar_pointer,bind,block,block_item,block_list,bob_data,
 bookmark_conference,bookmark_storage,bookmark_url,
 bytestreams,caps,carbons_disable,carbons_enable,
 carbons_private,carbons_received,carbons_sent,chatstate,
 compress,compress_failure,compressed|...]
```

**If you're doing this in an erlang shell, make sure you import those record definitions BEFORE you try executing the code to grab the room state and subject!**

Also, be careful about doing this from a callback that is executed by the muc room's process itself.  The call to p1_fsm:sync_send_all_state_event( ) sends a message to the room process, and that will time out if you're sending it to your own process and blocking.  Do the query for the room state from another process!